# Redirect old ugly links to new ones with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I managed to sort out the links in htaccess and now all my links look fine. However, the old "*&category?item*" links are still there.
I want to redirect these to the new ones to avoid being seen as duplicate content by search engines.

Here's the .htaccess code I currently have (and which works fine)

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?category=$1
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$ index.php?category=$1

    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2

    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ item.php?category=$1&name=$2
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$ item.php?category=$1&name=$2

    RewriteRule ^download/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ download.php?category=$1&name=$2
    RewriteRule ^download/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$ download.php?category=$1&name=$2      
</IfModule>
```

Eg. http://alienvalley.com/item.php?category=mockups&name=clean-browser-mockup
and http://alienvalley.com/mockups/clean-browser-mockup/ are both working... How do I get the first one to redirect to the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this part of your code

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?category=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$ index.php?category=$1
```

leads also to duplicate content.
You must choose a scheme **with** or **without** *trailing slash*.

Looks like you already chosen **with** because you have a rule to add trailing slash (so it's ok but your rules without trailing slash are useless now).

Here's how your htaccess would look like

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?category=([^&]+)&page=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?category=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/item\.php\?category=([^&]+)&name=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/download\.php\?category=([^&]+)&name=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . download/%1/%2/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ item.php?category=$1&name=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^download/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ download.php?category=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, although I don't understand half of the code because I'm a htaccess noob, this is exactly what I needed! You're great!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this right below the `RewriteBase /` line:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index\.php\?category=([^&\ ]+)($|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index\.php\?category=([^&\ ]+)&(?:page|name)=([^&\ ]+)($|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /download\.php\?category=([^&\ ]+)&name=([^&\ ]+)($|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /download/%1/%2/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /item.php?category=$1&name=$2 [QSA,L]
```

this will redirect any url that does have a file or directory that exists so

```
http://alienvalley.com/default/clean-browser/
```

will also redirect to

```
http://alienvalley.com/item.php?category=default&name=clean-browser
```